# Report upgraded to SSRS 2008 R2 now renders badly in default document mode

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have installed a new RS 2008 R2 server to replace my RS 2005 server - most reports work and render just fine in the new server, but for one report, the text in the headings and some of the text boxes is shifted and partially cut off in the default document mode (IE5 quirks) that the report renders in.  If I press F12 and switch to any other document mode, the report re-renders just fine.

Is there something I can do to switch the default document mode or is there some other way to fix this?  A lot of people use this report so the workaround is not ideal.

Comment: If you haven't yet, try editing the report in BIDS 2008R2, which will upgrade the report (.rdl) format. This is a one-way upgrade so keep a copy of the old .rdl around. Then upload the upgraded rdl to SSRS, and see if that improves things.

Comment: Thanks Jamie - I did open the file in and deploy from BIDS 2008R2 - I was not aware of any upgrading process on the RDL when I did this, but in any case, the problem persists